# mmap PCIe BAR and print content of addr is ffffffff

Tags: c, linux-kernel, mmap, pci-e

I tried to use mmap() in the linux user mode to map the resource2 file in sysfs to obtain the BAR of the pcie device. The code is shown below.

```
char *devname = "/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:04:00.2/resource2";
res_fd = open(devname, O_RDWR);
if (res_fd < 0)
    goto fail;
map_addr = mmap(NULL, pci->mem_resource[i].len,
        PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
        MAP_SHARED, res_fd, 0);
if (map_addr == MAP_FAILED)
    goto fail;
printf ("%x\n", ((unsigned char*)map_addr)[0x100]);
```

Finally, the output of this code is ffffffff.

I am very sure that this is abnormal. I checked the datasheet of the device and its output should be a fixed constant, such as 0x37e3cf5.

Actually, I got ffffffff on ubuntu 18.04 kernel 4.19+, but the correct 0x37e3cf5 on ubuntu 18.04 kernel 5.4+.

I want to know what caused the difference of pcie's source file in sysfs. It has tortured me for a long time

Thank you!

Comment: Look at the output of `cat /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:04.00.2/enable`. If it prints `1` access to BAR regions is enabled. If it prints `0` access to BAR regions is disabled. You can enable it with `sudo sh -c 'echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:04:00.2/enable'` and try again.

Comment: At the physical PCI device level, that sysfs `enable` attribute is operating on bits 0 and 1 of the 16-bit Command register at offset 4 of the device's PCI configuration space.

Comment: hi @IanAbbott, Thank you very much for your reply. I forget mention that sysfs enable is `1` ,But I tried to modify value of `enable`, first echo 0 and then echo 1, Hope to refresh the device.But I got `bash: echo: write error: Device or resource busy`, I used lspci -v to check the device, the reason for busy may be that the device has been bound by the driver. I think `enable` may not be the key to the problem

Comment: The code shown prints an unsigned char, which should never print as ffffffff and certainly cannot print as 37e3cf5.

Comment: `readlink '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:04:00.2/driver'` should show if the device is bound to a driver.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer shortly after the question was posted, it may be caused by AMD’s Secure Memory Encryption function, so I turned off the sme function in the kernel parameters of gurb and everything was normal.